# How to use structure in a structure?

Tags: c, windows, struct

This coulde be a dumm question, but i can't figure it out what i am doing wrong( i haven't used two structures in each other ).

I have two structures:

```
struct test
{
    struct ddata* difference;
    int diff;
};
struct test *MSG; 

struct ddata  
{
    char *filename;
    char *size;
};
struct ddata *difference
```

And i want to give them values this way (and my program freezes out here):

```
  MSG->difference = difference;  
  MSG->diff = diff;
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

kampi

EDIT:

The difference struct variable is created in one of my function (and in there i want to give value to my MSG structure). The MSG struct variable is declared globally(i don't know if this is relevant or not). The difference value is declared and filled up this way:

```
struct ddata *difference = (struct ddata *) malloc( dif * sizeof *difference );    
memset( difference, 0, dif * sizeof *difference ); 
...
...
...
difference[diff].filename = strdup( primary[i].filename );
difference[diff].size = strdup( primary[i].size );
diff++;
```

I hope i gave you what you need.

Comment: Are you allocating any memory to those pointers? It would probably help us to see what the problem is if you gave a small, complete example that was able to be compiled.

And by the way, you do not have two structures "in" each other (which is possible, but it's not what you have here). You have one structure that contains a pointer to another structure.

Comment: The naming scheme is making it hard for me to concentrate on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to do something like this:

```
MSG = (test* )malloc(sizeof(test));
```

?

Comment: Oooo. Thank you very much. I really forgot to use malloc. This is because i'm awake for 36 hours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing `MSG` before using it?  It has to point someplace valid before anything is assigned into it.  One way to do that is

```
MSG = malloc (sizeof *MSG);
```

Then it would be valid to set fields in *MSG, as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to call

```
free(MSG);
```

Also you can check your code using Valgrind which would have spotted that stack dump. Here is any example.

```
valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./your_application
```

Hope this helps,